# Creating winforms help file

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008

I'm looking to create a indexable help file for a winforms app, but how do you get started?

The Microsoft MSDN is rubbish, it says "create a new project" but doesn't specify which type to create.

How do I go about creating a help file for my applications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for this

[Integrating "Help" into WinForms Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158901/integrating-help-into-winforms-application)?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this doesn't count as a real answer:

I would vote against those help files. 5-6 years back we had real context sensitive help files on a per-dialog-basis in our applications, and it was a *lot* of effort to maintain those.

Therefore, we changed this to shipping "simple" PDF files that appear on `F1`. We never got any complaints from users.

Recently we started migrating this to real HTML websites with lots of individual pages, a search function, "prev" and "next" navigation, and a printer-friendly format. This enables us to update the manual much quicker and makes it more "linkable" compared to PDF.

Personally, I really never get warm with those help files. E.g. I still do not understand why some files need to be trusted, before I can open and view them.